# Get data next to eachother

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, gmail

I've made a script for sending bulk emails from google sheet.
However I stumbled across a problem.
For some reason I'm not able to get the data below next to each other.

```
var open = row[1] + row[2] + row[3]
```

Beneath you will find a piece of the google sheet list.
I use a vlookup on ID number to insert that data next to the message of the pupil/mail adress.

[image]

In my message I have an introduction (hello pupil, etc.)
After, they get (or should get) a list of their points.

```
var message = introduction + '\n\n' + open  + '\n\n\n' + ending; // setup of the mail
```

However, when they receive the mail it looks like this

```
Sarah
Sarah
Chemistry
Maths
9,5
6,0
```

Is there a way to get this data next to each?
like `\n` for new paragraph.

Thanks in advance

Edit:
It should look like this.

```
Sarah     Maths         9,5
Sarah     Chemistry     6,0
```

Edit2:

Macro i use to merge columns

```
function merge_col() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Open invoices');
  var data = ss.getDataRange().getValues();
  var header = data.shift();
  var col1 = data[1][0];
  var col2 = '';
  var col3 = '';
  var col4 = '';
  var dataSheet2 = [header];
  for(var i=0 ; i<data.length ; i++){
    Logger.log(data[i][0]+'  -  '+col1+'  -  '+data[i][2])
    if(col1==data[i][0]){
      col1 = data[i][0];
      col2+=data[i][1]+'\n';
      col3+=data[i][2]+'\n';
      col4+=data[i][3]+'\n';
    }else{
      dataSheet2.push([col1,col2,col3,col4]); 
      var col1 = data[i][0];
      col2 = data[i][1]+'\n';
      col3 = data[i][2]+'\n';
      col4 = data[i][3]+'\n';
    }
  }
  dataSheet2.push([col1,col2,col3,col4]); 
  Logger.log(dataSheet2);
  var sheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet3');
  sheet2.clear();
  sheet2.getRange(1, 1, dataSheet2.length, dataSheet2[0].length).setValues(dataSheet2);
}
```

Comment: This is because the content of each cell contains a line break. You will need to subdivide each cell that has multi-line content, and update your processing to add first halves with first halves and also any wholes in the same row.

Comment: @TheMaster : I've added an edit in the post with how it should look like
The comment from tehhowch is correct.

Is there maybe a way to copy the range of these 3 rows as a table into the mail?

Comment: Yes, subdivide each cell, splitting the string content on the internal line break(s). You'd have an easier time if your data structure did not have internal line breaks, and instead had separate rows for each repeated class ID.

Comment: @tehhowch : the problem im having with the subdivided cells is that i'm only getting the first value.
If i would search for Sarah i would only get her Maths numbers.
If i search for Sarah i should get all her numbers and that table copied into Gmail.

Comment: @TheMaster the cells are originally divided

In the original post i've put the script i use to merge the cells
I used that to merge the cells so i could get all the data with a vlookup
that way 1 ID would only have 1 row instead of multiple ones

Comment: `=FILTER(A1:D10,B1:B10="Sarah")`

Answer (score 0):

## Splicing Rows

The code:

```
function splicingRows(){
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var rg=sh.getDataRange();
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++){
    var maxrh=1;
    for(var j=0;j<vA[i].length;j++){//calculate max needed row height to fit all strings that are delimited with linefeeds
      if(vA[i][j]){
        var rh=vA[i][j].toString().split('\n').length;
        if(rh>maxrh){
          maxrh=rh;
        }
      }
    }
    var r=maxrh;
    if(r>1){//splice in the number of extra rows to fit the extra strings
      while(r>1){
        var vB=vA[i].slice();//dont forget the slice so that they are not the same array they need to be copies
        vA.splice(i,0,vB);
        r--;
      }
      r=maxrh;
      while(r>0){
        var k=maxrh-r
        for(var j=0;j<vA[i].length;j++){
          if(vA[i+k][j].toString().split('\n').length>1){//if there is more than one string then adjust the contents
            if(r<=vA[i+k][j].toString().split('\n').length){
              vA[i+k][j]=vA[i+k][j].toString().split('\n')[r-1];
            }else{
               vA[i+k][j]=null;
            }
          }else{
            vA[i+k][j]=vA[i+k][j];//if there is only one then just copy it.
          }
        }
        r--;
      }
    }

  }
  sh.getRange(1,1,vA.length,vA[0].length).setValues(vA);//replace the entire page all at one time
}
```

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]